# How to alert var distance_all (from var distance_top + distance_bottom)?

Tags: javascript, jquery

How to alert var `distance_all` (from var `distance_top + distance_bottom`)?

When mouse position `top` or `bottom`  less than 100 px. it's will be alert `distance_all` (from var `distance_top + distance_bottom`).

But not work , How can i do that?

http://jsfiddle.net/dyjb8r9w/1/

```
<script>

$(window).load(function(){


(function() {

    var mY, distance_top,
        $distance_top = $('#distance_top span'),
        $element_top  = $('#element_top');

    function calculatedistance_top(elem , mouseY) {
        return Math.floor(Math.sqrt(Math.pow(mouseY - (elem.offset().top+(elem.height()/2)), 2)));
    }

    $(document).mousemove(function(e) {        
        mY = e.pageY;
        distance_top = calculatedistance_top($element_top , mY);
        $distance_top.text(distance_top);

        if (distance_top < 100) 
        { distance_all = distance_bottom + distance_top;
          alert(distance_all);}  
    });
})();




(function() {

    var mY, distance_bottom,
        $distance_bottom = $('#distance_bottom span'),
        $element_bottom  = $('#element_bottom');

    function calculatedistance_bottom(elem , mouseY) {
        return Math.floor(Math.sqrt(Math.pow(mouseY - (elem.offset().top+(elem.height()/2)), 2)));
    }

    $(document).mousemove(function(e) {        
        mY = e.pageY;
        distance_bottom = calculatedistance_bottom($element_bottom , mY);
        $distance_bottom.text(distance_bottom);  

        if (distance_bottom < 100) 
        { distance_all = distance_bottom + distance_top;
          alert(distance_all);}  

    });
})();

});
</script>
```

Comment: I see alert message when `distance_top` is less than 100.

Comment: Is [this](http://jsfiddle.net/dyjb8r9w/5/) you are looking for?

Comment: @ Bhushan Kawadkar i want to alert value `distance_bottom + distance_top`

Comment: And it is already alerted when `distance_bottom < 100`, isn't it?

Comment: @Regent yes , it's alert when < 100 but value that alert not ok.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`distance_bottom` doesn't have value inside first `mousemove` event handler. Splitting code into two separate `mousemove` event handlers with a lot of duplicating code is not a good idea at all.

Rewritten `<script>` code:

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/dyjb8r9w/10/).

```
$(document).ready(function()
{     
    var $distance_top = $('#distance_top span');
    var $element_top  = $('#element_top');
    var $distance_bottom = $('#distance_bottom span');
    var $element_bottom  = $('#element_bottom');

    function calculateDistance(elem, mouseY)
    {
        return Math.floor(Math.abs(mouseY - (elem.offset().top + elem.height() / 2)));
    }

    $(document).mousemove(function(e)
    {        
        var mY = e.pageY;
        var distance_top = calculateDistance($element_top, mY);
        var distance_bottom = calculateDistance($element_bottom, mY);
        $distance_top.text(distance_top);
        $distance_bottom.text(distance_bottom);
        if (distance_top < 100) 
        {
            var distance_all = distance_bottom + distance_top;
            alert(distance_all);
        }  
    });
});
```